# Rekey a Certificate with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, certificate

We have an API hosted in Azure AppService with a custom domain & SSL. Is it possible to rekey this certificate using a PowerShell script instead of using the Azure Portal UI? [which is done as below?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taAea.png)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this before, but looking at the documentation it seems like this may be it:

New-AzWebAppSSLBinding (and Remove-AzWebAppSSLBinding)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebappsslbinding?view=azps-2.4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/remove-azwebappsslbinding?view=azps-2.4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#powershell

Comment: Thanks. These documents are for binding/unbinding a certificate but not for actual rekey.